# How to covert Json to a Java Object auto-generated from Avro Schema

Tags: java, json, avro

I am trying to convert a JSON String to a Java Object in my code. The java object is an instance of a class auto-generated from an AVRO Schema. Does anyone know how to do this conversion?
Following are a few things I've tried so far with no luck.

I have tried using the ObjectMapper class from the Jackson library to convert json to the target java object, but ObjectMapper fails during the conversion.

I tried AvroMapper which exends ObjectMapper, part of the jackson-dataformats library, but couldn't figure out how to use it to convert json to an avro generated object.

I've noticed that every auto-generated Avro Java class has a method named "fromByteBuffer()", I tried using that method also hoping that if I pass my json as java.nio.ByteBuffer to that method then it would return me an instance of the Object.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you've tried, and show how it fails. Please read this before editing question: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Basically, you need to **edit** the question and show us a *reduced* version of the class, the JSON you're trying to map into that class, the code you're using to do that, and show the errors you get, with full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

The `AvroMapper` should have various readValue methods inherited from the `ObjectMapper` class. Try using one of those and provide the class.

```
avroMapper.readValue(json, Car.class);
```